# Calculate how many ArrayLists are in an ArrayList in Java

Tags: java, arraylist

Is there away of finding out how many Lists an ArrayList holds?

`ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>> myList = new ArrayList<ArrayList<Integer>>();`
`List<Integer> myOtherList = new LinkedList<Integer>();`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As with any list, you can find out how many objects it is holding with [`List#size()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html#size%28%29).

```
int size = myList.size(); // amount of sublists that myList holds
```

Comment: Oh, of course. I can't believe i didn't think of this. Thank you. :D

Comment: We all have those days, no worries ;) Just don't forget to mark the answer as accepted when you can.

Answer (score 2):

@Vulcan's response will get you the size of the list. If you want only the ArrayLists contained within the List, you'll need to check the element type using instanceof and increment the count that way:

```
int listcount = 0;
for (Object e : list) {
   if (e instanceof ArrayList) listcount++;
}
```